# How to change Google Sites access permissions after 48hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm looking for a function to notify clients they have 48hours to download a set of documents then remove client access to Google sites after the 48hrs. The timed event handler doesn't seem to really provide this functionality??

```
function Remove_people( site_name, client_email ) {
    var domain = "mydomain.com" ;
    var site = SitesApp.getSite(domain, site_name );
    site.removeEditor( client_email );

    // Some counter-timer function??? 

    the_url = site.getUrl();

    //email a link to the client
    MailApp.sendEmail(client_email, 
                    "Your Documents are ready!", 
                    "Your documents are accessible for 48hrs at the url below: \n\n " +
                     the_url + "\n\n",                   
                    {name:"My Name"});*/


    Logger.log("Done!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the email address and the timestamp in a spreadsheet or using scriptDB. 
In another function, check this timestamp against the current time and remove the user if 48 hours have elapsed. You can have this second function run under a timed trigger set to run every hour or so.

Comment: I agree, I would do it this way. But I am not sure how to do the download side. I have not seen anyone trigger a download via GAS. - I guess you could create a copy of the document for each user, and then delete it after 48 hours.